# XNA - enter key

Tags: c#, input, keyboard

I am trying to figure out how to input the enter key in xna. I already know how to input the other keys(e.x. backspace, letters and special characters), but i am having a hard time figuring out how to do the Enter key.

```
 if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter) && prevKb.IsKeyUp(Keys.Enter))
        {
            input = input + " ";
        }
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: There's like a _squillion_ Microsoft samples and tutorials for this

Comment: i didn't find anything to match. If you could please comment a link to it that will be much appreciated

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816871/6138713

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks, to me, like you are having difficulty adding an "enter" keystroke (also know as a line-break) to a string.

Instead of using the code `input = input + " ";` try using `input += "/n";`.  It functions similarly to the `<br>` tag in HTML.

The /n character is a command that allows you to insert line-breaks into a string.

I hope I was able to help,
-GHC